# Совместное употребление союзов "ли" и "или"

Tags: синтаксис

Мне всегда казались слабо сочетающимися союзы "ли" и "или" в предложениях типа "Независимо от того, будет ли... или нет". Я привыкла их слышать без союза "ли", который здесь кажется лишним. С другой стороны, если этот союз опустить, как присоединить придаточное предложение без подчинительного союза? Так вот вопрос: возможно ли построение предложений такого типа без союза "ли"?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какую конструкцию Вы имеете в виду.
Уточните, пожалуйста, или приведите пример той, которую зотите оценить на правильность. 
Я не вижу никаких проблем в построении бессоюзного предложения по Вашему примеру: "Независимо, будет или нет..."

Comment: Запятая в бессоюзном предложении ставится только в том случае, если между его частями складываются перечислительные отношения. В данном случае мы имеем придаточную изъяснительную, поэтому, если мы хотим построить это предложение как бессоюзное, между его частями следует ставить двоеточие, которое здесь совершенно неуместно ("Независимо от того: будет... или нет".) А если еще учесть, что здесь есть указательное слово, то построение бессоюзных сентенций станет и вовсе немыслимым.

Comment: >Запятая в бессоюзном предложении ставится только в том случае, если между его частями складываются перечислительные отношения.   
  
Пардон?!

>построить это предложение как бессоюзное, между его частями следует ставить двоеточие  
  
Нет. Я вообще не погнимаю, как и зачем в этом контексте вы противопоставляте "пречислительное" "изъяснительному".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложение возможно и без союза ЛИ,  в таком случае оно будет бессоюзным, изъяснительные отношения сохраняются, запятая тоже.

Независимо от того, будет дождь или нет, мы поедем к морю.

Подобные примеры (правда, без союза или, но с изъяснительными отношениями в БСП) можете найти в Грамматике п.3184
[здесь](http://rusgram.narod.ru/3182-3194.html)

Comment: Спасибо, однако примеры в правиле по ссылке в целом вторят рекомендациям школьной программы по расстановке знаков препинания  (правда, пунктуационное оформление некоторых предложений прямо-таки озадачивает), поэтому я склонна пока соглашаться с умопостроениями Софии относительно подчинительной связи.

Comment: Это не правила, это академическая грамматика, составленная ведущими грамматистами. Она не "вторит рекомендациям школьной программы", а содержит описание грамматической системы русского языка. Если между частями  сложного предложения нет средства связи - это бессоюзное предложение. А отношения могут быть похожи как на отношения в СПП, так и в СПП. Но от этого они союзными не становятся.

Comment: Да, нельзя не согласиться. Еще раз спасибо, Ларf.

Answer (score 1):

Просто хочется разбавить серьезные рассуждения и споры...

ЛИ и ИЛИ навеяли забавное воспоминание. 
  Смотрели как-то с мужем передачу о Пеле. Там была фраза: "Играет ли он за Сантос или за какую-либо другую команду...". Свекровь, выходившая из комнаты, услышала только часть, ей послышалось: "Играет Лион Зассантос". Она возмущалась, как не повезло футболисту с фамилией. А у нас это теперь семейная байка.)

Comment: Гы.............

Comment: Да, без ЛИ меняется акцент в предложении. Но построение самого предложения, мне кажется, практически не изменяется.

Comment: Спрашивающий считает, что это предложение сложноподчиненное с придаточным изъяснительным, которое присоединяется подчинительным союзом ЛИ. Но это ЛИ ему хочется опустить. Останется ли предложение правильным? (Я правильно поняла?)

Comment: Ларf, совершенно верно поняли, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем нам  нужна частица ЛИ, каково ее значение?  Она бывает одиночной, и в этом случае считается вопросительной, но  это не простой, а подчеркнутый (усиленный)  вопрос, да еще  выражающий  сомнение и неуверенность в положительном ответе. Частица ЛИ также  входит во многие  разделительные союзы ИЛИ, ИЛИ…ИЛИ, ТО ЛИ…ТО ЛИ, кроме того,  в союз ЕСЛИ. Но это общие рассуждения,  а теперь попробуем рассмотреть вопрос конкретный.

1. Зная, что будет дождь, вы всё-таки поехали к морю. Это классическое придаточное изъяснительное предложение с союзом ЧТО.
2. Независимо от того, (что) будет ли  дождь или нет, мы поедем к морю. Здесь сочинительный союз ЛИ…ИЛИ играет роль пропущенного подчинительного союза ЧТО.

Сходные предложения с пропущенным союзом ЧТО: Трудно было понять, был ли там  пожар, или же собиралась всходить луна. Неясно было, то ли дым идёт от костра, то ли туман стелется над лугом. Я не знал,  не то  я стою на опушке леса, не то за поляной начинается густая чаща.

1. Независимо от того, (что) будет (ли)  дождь или нет, мы поедем к морю. Здесь мы пропускаем оба союза (ЧТО и ИЛИ) и поэтому имеем СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, которое трудно узнать. Тем не менее,  приходится считать его СПП, так как запятая в БСП ставится только при  сочинительной связи входящих в его состав предложений.
2. Что мы получаем, пропуская частицу ЛИ? Наверное, дополнительные оттенки значений. В простом, бытовом предложении это смотрится нормально, но в художественных текстах звучит не лучшим образом, например: «Паду я, стрелой пронзенный, иль мимо пролетит она?»