# Трактовка знаков

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Не бойтесь,(кстати)я опытный.
Не бойтесь - (так как)я опытный.

Правильно ли я трактую знаки?
Или верен один вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В БСП часто бывает очень важной авторская позиция. Иногда предложения связаны по смыслу, но автор не считает нужным ОБОЗНАЧАТЬ  эту связь. Тогда мы пишем:"не бойтесь, я опытный". Но эту же связь можно обозначить (подчеркнуть):"не бойтесь - я опытный". В устной речи во втором предложении делается пауза.

Здесь лучше поставить тире в связи с небольшим объемом предложений. Увеличенная предупредительная пауза, соответствующая двоеточию, сюда не вписывается.

Comment: > В БСП часто бывает очень важной авторская позиция. Иногда предложения связаны по смыслу, но автор не считает нужным ОБОЗНАЧАТЬ эту связь. Тогда мы пишем:"не бойтесь, я опытный". Но эту же связь можно обозначить (подчеркнуть):"не бойтесь - я опытный". В устной речи во втором предложении делается пауза.

Спасибо, что прокомментировали, мне больше всех надо. Но узнать источник этой информации было бы вообще в кайф.

Comment: К сожалению, это только наблюдение и обобщение той темы, которую мы называем авторским решением. Обычно после слова "авторский знак" комментарии не следуют - видно,  составители учебников целиком полагаются на авторскую интуицию.

Comment: Ясно, благодарю за разъяснения.

Answer (score 0):

Если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения указывает причину того, о чем говорится в первой, - ставится двоеточие. Однако в последнее время наблюдается тенденция к замене двоеточия тире в БСП причины (простите, источник информации утрачен). Более того, [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26241/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8) утверждается правомерность замены и тире, и двоеточия запятой независимо от смысловых отношений, существующих между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения. Об этом мне самой хотелось бы узнать больше.